# Reduce HTTP requests in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-3

I have many tile layers in a map.So when I zoom or move the map,all layers will send wms request to the server.How can I reduce HTTP requests when zoom the map by merging different layer's request to a single request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your WMS layers come from the same server, you can combine them into a single `ol.layer.Layer` object, more precisely in one source object by definining each layer in a comma separated list (under the `'LAYERS'` parameter):

```
    new ol.layer.Image({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states,topp:population'}, // <---
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })
```

There are other things you could try to reduce the number of requests / to enhance the overall performance:

- you mentioned "many tile layers", and then WMS requests.  If you're not using a tile caching method, you could look into that.  Example: [MapCache](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/).
- you could also do a single big tile request instead of many small ones to render you layer(s) (the example above does that).  This kind of approach reduces the number of requests, but you'll have the impression that the map is slower to render. It also make it less possible to "cache" the result, as the request of the tile is very often unique (depends on the extent of the map view).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maxTilesLoading option to change the number of asynchronous requests Openlayers send, at the same time, when interacting with a map i.e:

```
var map = new Map({
  maxTilesLoading:5,
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

The default is 16, but if you have tiles that take a second or two to load you can end up with a big backlog of unfinished requests being processed by the server. This is because browsers can only have around 10-20 active http requests to a server at the same time. Any more and the request will just hang until the queue reduces. This can make the site grind to a halt with increasing number of requests sent from the browser to the server just waiting for the queue of requests to reduce so that is can get processed. Constantly moving/zooming a map will send a large number of http requests from the browser to the server. Reducing this with maxTilesLoading reduces the chances of overloading the number of requests. The trade off is the map might load a little slower at first as more work is being done in series, but it vastly improves the overall performance when interacting with the map.